# Is a closure of subspace N and and orthogonal complement of this subspace N orthogonal?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Ok, there is something I do not understand about what I run into today in an online document. I know it might sound simple but I am so new to topology so I am having hard time to understand.

As we know that, a Hilbert space is a complete inner product with every Cauchy sequence in this space is convergent. Today I find something in this document which I'll give it in quotation below.

> Given either an open or closed subset of N of a Hilbert space H, we
>   define its orthogonal complement as the space:
>
> $N^{\top}=\{l \in H: \langle l,g\rangle=0, \forall g\in\bar{N}\} $
>
> noting that the only instance when $\langle g,g\rangle=0$ is if g is identically
>   zero which implies that $\bar{N}\cap N^{\top}=\{0\}$. The direct sum
>   of these complementary spaces, the closure of N and its orthogonal
>   complement $N^{\top}$, both of which are Hilbert spaces themselves,
>   equals H:
>
> $H=\bar{N}\bigoplus N^{\top}=\{g+l: g\in \bar{N}\; \text{and}\; l \in 
> > N^{\top}\}$
>
> although the union of these same subspaces need not cover H:
>
> $\bar{N}\cup N^{\top}\subseteq H$

Can someone care to explain me how this is possible? I mean that why it is "closure of N" and not N itself?

Is it related with that $\bar{N}^{\top}=N^{\top}$?

Comment: Exactly. The closure of the subspace and the subspace give the same orthogonal complement. This is because of the continuity of the inner product.

Comment: ok, thank you but why do we need to use closure of N, instead of N itself?

Comment: If we have $H=N\oplus M$, where $M$is the space that we know is closed (in your case the orthogonal complement), and $N$ contained in the orthogonal complement of $M$, we also have the projection $N\oplus M\rightarrow M$ continuous (If $\{a_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $M$ the projection is given as $p_M(x):=\sum (x,a_i)a_i$). The kernel of it is $N$, which being the preimage of a closed set $\{0\}$ must be closed.

Comment: I am so silly. I do not understand it. because it says here that "Given either an open or closed subset of N "

Comment: Whoever wrote that doesn't know what he is talking about. $N$ doesn't have to be open or closed in order to define the orthogonal complement. The orthogonal complement can be defined for any subset. On the other hand they forgot to ask for $N$ to be a linear subspace. This is not needed to define $N^{\bot}$ but it is needed to have $\overline{N}\oplus N^{\bot}=H$.

Comment: Ok I think why he says "given either an open or closed subset N" is about defining $H=\bar{N}\bigoplus N^{\top}$. As you check Corollary 6.15 in https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch6.pdf , you can see that if N is not closed, the direct sum is written like that. So it does not say that N should be a linear subspace to write this direct sum. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Open or closed is not important for anything. It could be neither open nor closed.

Comment: So only this subspace should be linear, in order to define a direct sum?

Comment: What is the definition of direct sum? Direct sum of what? Direct sum of Hilbert spaces. The summands must be Hilbert spaces. In particular they are linear spaces. If you take something that is only a subset and take the closure you may not even get a vector subspace. A closed vector subspace is what gives you a Hilbert subspace. If you don't study the definitions of the things you are working with there is no way you are going to understand anything at all.